# How can I make Windows 7 remember my last opened Explorer folders even after a crash?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I have been using "Tools -> Folder options -> View -> Restore previous folder windows at logon" but I find that it's inadequate.
When shutting down or restarting Windows 7 normally, this feature works.

However, any abnormal termination (blue screen of death, pressing the power button, turning off the electricity, etc) will mean that Windows doesn't remember your last session's opened Explorer folders.

What can I do to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Windows does not support this. Such folder information is only saved on normal termination of the explorer.exe process. Otherwise it has no opportunity to do so.